# Run Ratchet php server without need of cli

Tags: php, websocket, command-line-interface, ratchet, phpwebsocket

I am implementing a websocket real time chat with [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/docs/) 
It's working fine, The problem is that I need to run **server.php** via command line so this way the server will work, I can not run the file directly 
 I tried via:

> exec()

And other methods but it fails to run the server, anyone have an alternative or a solution?

server.php

```html
<?php

use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;

   
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'class/SimpleChat.php';

   
$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new SimpleChat()
        )
    ),
    8080
);

$server->run();
```

/class/SimpleChat.php

```html
<?php

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class SimpleChat implements MessageComponentInterface
{
    /** @var SplObjectStorage  */
    protected $clients;

    /**
     * SimpleChat constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        conectados
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    /**
     * @param ConnectionInterface $conn
     */
    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
       
        $this->clients->attach($conn);
        echo "Cliente conectado ({$conn->resourceId})" . PHP_EOL;
    }

    /**
     * @param ConnectionInterface $from
     * @param string $data
     */
    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $data)
    {
        
        $data = json_decode($data);
        $data->date = date('d/m/Y H:i:s');

        
        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            $client->send(json_encode($data));
        }

        echo "User {$from->resourceId} sent you a message" . PHP_EOL;
    }

    /**
     * @param ConnectionInterface $conn
     */
    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
        $this->clients->detach($conn);
        echo "User {$conn->resourceId} Disconnected" . PHP_EOL;
    }

    /**
     * @param ConnectionInterface $conn
     * @param Exception $e
     */
    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e)
    {
        
        $conn->close();

        echo "Error {$e->getMessage()}" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have been into the same problem. Solved it using cURL. Use the following command to
start ratchet server without the need of cli.

```
$handle = curl_init();
 $url = 'Path-to-your-server-file/App/server.php';
 curl_setopt($handle,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
 curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1); 
 $data = curl_exec($handle);
 curl_close($handle);
 print_r($handle);
```